# When condition met, jump to next object in list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I run a loop through a list of customers 'customer in filteredAndApprovedQBCustomers', I use a service to check if this 'customer' has a customerInfo record.

If they do have a customerInfo record but their 'businessCategory' column in not selected display "No Business Category exists..." **& JUMP TO NEXT CUSTOMER IN LIST**

If they do have a customerInfo record but their 'businessCategory' is selected **& JUMP TO NEXT CUSTOMER IN LIST**

If they do not have a customerInfo record, create one and display "No business category exists..."

I have tried to jump to next cust in the list by using **break** which jumps out of the list and **return** which shows `an object of type convertibale System.Web.MVC.ActionResult is required`

any ideas?

Comment: You describe the code, but don't show it.  Can you please show some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx) statement instead of break.

Comment: thats great thanks for the help tucaz